# Is it possible to remove inactive code with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am importing [lodash](https://lodash.com/) into my project, but the main script doesn't use more than 5 lodash functions, I don't want to fill my project with unused/inactive code, is there a way to check the whole project structure and delete the inactive code on bundle/on build?

### Example:

**index.html**

```html
<body>
  <script src="lodash.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**lodash.js**

```js
function a() {
  console.log('Hi')
}

function b() {
  console.log('I am not used anywhere')
}
```

**app.js**

```js
...
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', a)
...
```

Function b() is not used in the project.

### Question:

How to get rid of inactive code *function b()* automatically?

Comment: After all, you have exactly selected in the link you provided how to use only selected functions - `var array = require('lodash/array');`

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Your method is very manual, is there a way to automate it without human interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), a pattern that decides which code is dead code and should not be included in the bundle. One of the requirements to use this with Webpack is to use [ES Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/). If you're using already webpack to bundle `app.js`, you should `import` to import lodash inside your project, instead of adding it as a dependency in your html file.

Keep in mind that this will only work if lodash is using ES Modules, if that's not the case there's always [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es)